# How to change a div border color on a checkbox click

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, blazor

I have a custom checkbox that works like a slider. You click the button, it slides across and changes color to green..

[Unchecked checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geb3j.png)

clicked

[Checked checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cayf6.png)

Now, i am trying to figure out, how i could use the same kind of css to change the border color of the surrounding button..

[I want to change this border, on checkbox checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFrLr.png)

Here is my custom css for the checkbox/slider

```
.checkbox{
                            position:relative;
                            cursor:pointer;
                            appearance:none;
                            width:37px;
                            height:24px;
                            border-radius:20px;
                            border:2px solid #ccc;
                            outline:none;
                            transition:0.3s;
                            border-color:red;
                        }
                        .checkbox::before{
                            content:"";
                            position:absolute;
                            height:15px;
                            width:15px;
                            border-radius:50%;
                            background:red;
                            top:2px;
                            left:0px;
                            transition:0.3s ease-in-out;
                        }
                        .checkbox:checked::before{
                            transform:translateX(18px);
                            background:green;
                        }
                        .checkbox:checked{
                            border-color:green;
                        }
```

And implementation of the checkbox/slider

```
    <div class="float-container">
                                                    <div class="float-child">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(role.Description, eventArgs.Value); }"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="float-child">
                                                        <p>Application Role - </p>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <p><b>@role.Description</b></p>
                                                        <br/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

So, i want to implement the same kind of logic to my float logic - css below 

.float-container {
                            border: 3px solid #fff;
                            padding: 20px;
                        }

                        .float-child {
                            width: 100%;
                            padding: 20px;
                            border: 2px solid seagreen;
                            text-align-last: center;
                        }
```

I am sure this will be easy for somone who is a whizz at CSS. Im still learning..

EDIT****

So it looks like this can only be done in JS, judging by the comments.. I haven't used js yet, but id be greatful for the help.. So i guess the JS needs to know, when i have selected the checkbox, to change the color of my border in float-child.

**UPDATE*****

So i figured it out using Javascript - using this script to replace css items when the checkbox was checked - But having other issues, i guess my foreach loop needs unique id's.. not sure how to achieve it, in a dynamic list.. But this code below may help some one, whos not working with dynamic.

First add id's to the elements you want changing

```
<div class="float-child" Id="floatdiv">
<input type="checkbox" Id="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

And then my javascript to change the css elements..

```
function BorderColorChangeOnCheckboxClick(){
    $('[id*=checkbox]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#floatdiv").css("width", "100%");
            $("#floatdiv").css("padding", "20px");
            $("#floatdiv").css("border", "2px solid red");
            $("#floatdiv").css("text-align-last", "center");
        }
        
        else {
            $("#floatdiv").css("width", "100%");
            $("#floatdiv").css("padding", "20px");
            $("#floatdiv").css("border", "2px solid seagreen");
            $("#floatdiv").css("text-align-last", "center");
        }
    });
};
```

Don't forget, if you are working with Blazor.. To add the javascript file to your host files, and also make the JS interop call within your code.. ie

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
            {
                await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("search");
                await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("BorderColorChangeOnCheckboxClick");
    
            }
```

Hope this will help someone in the future..

So back to my code -

**FULL CODE**

```
<div hidden="@IsShow" class="text-center-middle">
                        <div class="text-left mb-3">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 control-section">
                                <div class="control_wrapper">
                                    @if (AppRolesDetails != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (var role in AppRolesDetails)
                                        {
                                            <div class="float-container">
                                                <div class="float-child">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" Id="checkbox" class="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(role.Description, eventArgs.Value); }"/>
                                                </div>


                                                <div class="float-child">
                                                    <p>Application Role - </p>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <b>@role.Description</b>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <br/>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            AppOwnerCommonName = role.CommonName;
                                        }
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
                        .text-center-middle { margin-left: 58px; 
                        }
                        .checkbox {
                            appearance: none;
                            border: 2px solid #ccc;
                            border-color: red;
                            border-radius: 20px;
                            cursor: pointer;
                            height: 24px;
                            outline: none;
                            position: relative;
                            transition: 0.3s;
                            width: 37px;
                        }

                        .checkbox::before {
                            background: red;
                            border-radius: 50%;
                            content: "";
                            height: 15px;
                            left: 0px;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 2px;
                            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
                            width: 15px;
                        }

                        .checkbox:checked::before {
                            background: green;
                            transform: translateX(18px);
                        }

                        .checkbox:checked { border-color: green; }

                        .float-container {
                            border: 3px solid #fff;
                            padding: 20px;
                        }

                        .float-child {
                            border: 2px solid red;
                            padding: 20px;
                            text-align-last: center;
                            width: 100%;
                        }

                        .float-child-unknown {
                            border: 2px solid red;
                            padding: 20px;
                            text-align-last: center;
                            width: 100%;
                        }

                        .box-color-change {
                            border: 2px solid seagreen;
                            padding: 20px;
                            text-align-last: center;
                            width: 100%;
                        }
                    </style>
```

Comment: CSS can't target the parent of an element. Selectors only go forwards. JS is gonna be your best bet here unless you want to reflow your document so that the checkbox is a preceding sibling to the elements you want to change.

Comment: CSS full form itself is Cascading style sheet

Comment: Any idea, how to do it in js? So i need it to somehow know when the checkbox has been checked and then change that css class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any JS or jumping through hoops backwards CSS.

You're creating a custom control, so build a component to represent it.  I've not included your Css etc to keep the answer short, just used standard Bootstrap.

`MyCheckBox.razor`

```
<span class="p-2 border @borderColor">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="@_currentValue" @onchange="Changed" />
</span>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private string borderColor => _currentValue ? "border-success" : "border-danger";
    private bool _currentValue;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    => _currentValue = this.Value;

    private async Task Changed(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentValue = (bool)e.Value;
        if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_currentValue);
    }
}
```

`MyCheckBox.razor.css`

```
/*Add your custom css here */
```

Test page

```
@page "/"
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <MyCheckBox Value="value" ValueChanged="this.ValueChanged"></MyCheckBox>
</div>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    @this.value
</div>

@code {
    bool value;

    private void ValueChanged(bool value)
        {
        this.value = value;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely don't need JavaScript for that!

There's a trick to style form elements however you dream of. You just need to put your element right after the native input and wrap both with `<label>` to make it clickable:

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-native">
    <i class="checkbox-custom"></i>
</label>
```

Then, you can change the appearance of your custom element when the native checkbox is checked:

```css
.checkbox-native {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox-custom {
    display: inline-block;
    /* some general style */
}

:checked + .checkbox-custom {
    /* style only applicable when checked */
}
```

Comment: How will this work, i don't need to change the checkbox, the css already does this. I need to change the floatdiv border in which the checkbox resides.. unless im misunderstanding something?

Comment: Elements inside `<label>` control the input inside the same `<label>` and `+` operator in CSS means *the next neighbor*. In general, you shouldn't use `::before` and `::after` on inputs, because it's not a standard. It can stop working any time. And finally, styling checkboxes has some limitations. Using a separate element makes you totally free in terms of styling.

Comment: That didnt work, it says label cannot be nested inside a div - i will update to show you tho whole code

Comment: Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user17152873 right, I forgot about it. I edited my answer to use `<i>` instead. You can also use `<span>` or another inline element.

Comment: Ok, maybe you understood my issue wrong. I need to change the color of the border of the div, that the checkbox resides in. The checkbox is already changing color with the css i have..

Comment: Please read my comments again. Using `::before` or `::after` on input is wrong. If it works, it's just by browser implementation and can stop working any time. Use separate element like I did and do whatever you like with it. You can set different `border-color` inside the `:checked + .checkbox-custom {}`